# Someone is Editing my Answers by Randomly scratching out words and Another User is just Approving it?

Tags: support, editing

Please see The Review for "Buddhism Cure for insecurity".I appreciate editing any answers as long as it makes sense.This user just scratched words randomly then another user just approved it i think because he didn't read it.I don't know how else to flag this.Please Read reviews before you approve.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about [this review](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2375)? If so, the editor wasn't scratching out the words - just adding spaces between sentences. The review does make it look like words were getting scratched out, but I don't think that's what was happening there.

The review ended up being rejected, probably due to this misunderstanding, but I believe it was an edit in good faith.

Comment: oh...okaay....i didn't know.. it looked like on the left it was scratched out ... sorry about that..

Comment: @Orion: No problem. I can see how it looked super alarming at first!

Comment: I think it is more reader if the spacing is corrected as in the suggested edit. (I am not the editor)

Answer (score 2):

When you look at https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2375 there are two buttons (near the top left), which are named "rendered output" and "markdown".

To better see what was changed in an edit, I recommend you use the "markdown" view instead of the "rendered output" view.